# Align plots next to each other with knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I've been been using knitr for a couple of days now, it's great! :)

At the moment I'm struggling to align two plots next to each other in the output file (a PDF). From my understanding this should be achieved by setting `out.width='.4\\linewidth'` or something similar in the chunk-options.

The resulting plots are quite small, 2 would quite easily fit next to each other, but somehow, the get all placed beneath each other.

I am also having trouble to align latex-tables (`xtable`-output with `results='asis'`-option) to the left of the document. It would be great to write next to it.

Comment: Can you provide a simple minimal example .Rnw file that illustrates it not working?

Comment: using par(mfrow = c(1, 2)) in the code chunk doesn't do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since you haven't provided one, I will do so for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Side by side images:

\begin{figure}[htpb]
<<myChunk, fig.width=3, fig.height=2.5, out.width='.49\\linewidth', fig.show='hold'>>=
par(mar=c(4,4,.1,.1),cex.lab=.95,cex.axis=.9,mgp=c(2,.7,0),tcl=-.3)
plot(cars)
boxplot(cars$dist,xlab='dist')
@
\end{figure}

Ta da!

\end{document}
```

which results in something that looks roughly like this for me when I run **knitr**:

[image]

Note the fiddling with the `par` settings to make sure everything looks nice. You *will* have to tinker.

This minimal reproducible example was derived from the very detailed [examples](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/graphics/) on the **knitr** website.

**Edit**

To answer your second question, even though it's more of a pure LaTeX question, here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum}
%------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
This is where the table goes with text wrapping around it. You may 
embed tabular environment inside wraptable environment and customize as you like.
%------------------------------------------
\begin{wraptable}{l}{5.5cm}
\caption{A wrapped table going nicely inside the text.}\label{wrap-tab:1}
<<mychunk,results = asis,echo = FALSE>>=
library(xtable)
print(xtable(head(cars)),floating = FALSE)
@
\end{wraptable} 
%------------------------------------------
\lipsum[2] 
\par
Table~\ref{wrap-tab:1} is a wrapped table.
%------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Once again, I simply adapted code I found in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49323/6180) question at the *amazingly* helpful tex.stackexchange.com site.

Comment: What happens if you have two plots of very different sizes? I have to place the legend for a plot next to it, and don't know how to get it there.

Comment: How would you enter this into a standard **RMarkdown** chunk?