# R knitr - include graphics (ggplot2 object rendered in R code ) directly in a defined place

Tags: r, knitr

I am making my first steps with `knitr`, trying to generate a raport. In the raport, I include `R` code which generates a ggplot2 object that I want to be included directly below some text. To make it more detailed, the graphic is a pair of two separated plots, which I want to be placed parallelly, one next to another.

So far, I have been dealing with by using the `R` code: producing and saving a .pdf picture, and then reading this picture from file and including it in the report by `\includegraphics` command. However, it is no more a solution for me - I want the **plot to be generated simultaneously with the report by the `R` code** (in particular: not to be saved anywhere as a .pdf)

However, the code I tried to use did not work properly - it generates the 2 plots, but they are however:

**1) incorrectly placed** - 2 pages below (which is even not the end of the document!)

**2) I don't know how to place them in one row, with the defined size**.

Please be of some help! Thank you in advance!! [below my not working porperly `R` code]

```
\textit{Pic 1 title} Some pic description

\begin{figure}[h]


\subfigure[pic1 name]{

<<echo = F, eval = T, message=F, fig=TRUE>>=
# a function returning a ggplot2 object (with a proper parameters instead of "...")
plot.matrix.from.file(...)
@

% below there is a fragment of the code I used before (which includes a graphics directly from a .pdf file)
%\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{data/simulated.data/obs_pred_mean_Gini_r.pdf}
\label{pic1 label}
}


\subfigure[pic2 name]{

<<echo = F, eval = T, message=F>>=
# a function returning a ggplot2 object (with a proper parameters instead of "...")
plot.matrix.from.file(...)
@

% below there is a fragment of the code I used before (which includes a graphics directly from a .pdf file)
%\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{data/simulated.data/obs_pred_var_Gini_r.pdf}

\label{pic2 label}
}
\caption{caption for the pair of plots}


\end{figure}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Align plots next to each other with knitr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574552/align-plots-next-to-each-other-with-knitr)

Comment: thank ypu Adnrie, I need a few minutes to check if it solves my problem, and I will remove this post in case it does :)

Comment: Also if you want it to be in a specific place, don't make it a figure, which will float the plot to the "best" place for the layout.  You can also try `H` instead of `h`, which is more insistent that you really want the figure Here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see any problems using the `subcaption` package. See [example 104](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

You can include sub-figures using the \textbf{subcaption} package. For example,
Figure \ref{fig:test} contains \ref{fig:test-a} and \ref{fig:test-b}.

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  <<test-a, echo=FALSE, results='asis', fig.width=5, fig.height=5>>=
  plot(1:10)
  @
  \caption{This is Figure a. \label{fig:test-a}}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  <<test-b, echo=FALSE, results='asis', fig.width=5, fig.height=5>>=
  plot(rnorm(100))
  @
  \caption{This is Figure b. \label{fig:test-b}}
  \end{subfigure}
\caption{This figure contains two subfigures. \label{fig:test}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output as expected:

[image: subfigure and knitr]