# Align plots of different widths next to each other with knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574552/align-plots-next-to-each-other-with-knitr) I know how to align plots of same width next to each other, but I would like to have my first plot much wider than the second one (same height though, and the second plot needs to be square).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996567/knitr-how-to-show-two-plots-of-different-sizes-next-to-each-other) game me an idea to play with plot `layout`. So here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Side by side images:

\begin{figure}[htpb]
<<test, echo=FALSE, out.width='1\\linewidth'>>=
par(mar=c(2,2,.1,.1),cex.lab=.95,cex.axis=.9,mgp=c(2,.7,0),tcl=-.3)
layout(t(matrix(c(1,2))), widths=c(10,2), heights=c(2,2), TRUE)
plot(1:100)
plot(1:10)
@
\end{figure}
Ta da!
\end{document}
```

And here is the pdf I get:

[image]

So if it's the right approach, how can I get rid of the space at the top and the bottom?
And if it's not, what the right one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you just need to adjust the widths and heights maybe `layout(t(matrix(c(1,2))), widths=c(8,2), heights=4, TRUE)`

Comment: @rawr Thanks for your comment, I forgot to mention that I need my second plot to be square. I did try to play with widths and heights, but I always get this extra space at the top and the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fig.width=8, fig.height=2
```

should work. I usually avoid `out.width` altogether.