# Can't replicate MWE for side-by-side plots in knitr / R Markdown (HTML output)

Tags: r, plot, knitr, r-markdown

I found [this MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10575200/2954547) for side-by-side plots in Knitr+Latex, and I attempted to convert it to R Markdown using HTML output. This is what I tried:

````
```{r, fig.show='hold', fig.width=3, fig.height=2.5, out.width=".49\\textwidth"}
par(mar = c(4, 4, .1, .1), cex.lab = .95, cex.axis = .9, mgp = c(2, .7, 0), tcl = -.3)
plot(cars)
boxplot(cars$dist,xlab='dist')
```
````

However it seems to generate *nothing* at all. I'm having the same problem trying to replicate [this other MWE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117872/42902), too.

Is there something wrong in my setup? How can I get this to work with HTML and not just PDF?

Edit: using `mfrow` or otherwise messing with the graphics device itself isn't an option because the plotting function I'm using (`filled.contour`) unfortunately takes over `layout`.

Comment: I get both plots when I run your example, but the plots are one on top of the other. You neglected to include `fig.show="hold"` in your chunk parameters, which will give you the side-by-side plots. Another option for side-by-side plots would be `\`\`\`{r, fig.width=6, fig.height=2.5}
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(cars)
boxplot(cars$dist,xlab='dist')\`\`\``

Comment: @eipi10 my mistake, I do have `fig.show="hold"` in my code

Comment: When I use your (now updated code) with `fig.show = "hold"` this is a perfect plot witz both plots side-by-side as pdf. As HTML I see only the code and no plot.

Comment: @J_F I also forgot to specify I'd like to use HTML output -_-

Comment: In the RStudio viewer you see no plot, but when you open your *.html file in your output folder with a browser, you will see the two plots, but not side-by-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem: I had `fig.align='center'` enabled. Apparently this conflicts somehow with the ability to place two plots on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

The `out.width` directive is screwing things up. When you're not in LaTeX output mode, `out.width="0.49\\textwidth"` is meaningless ... (The other MWE you're referring to is also LaTeX style -- I don't know what you did to adapt it to HTML ...)

````
writeLines("
```{r, fig.show='hold', fig.width=3, fig.height=2.5}
    par(mar = c(4, 4, .1, .1), cex.lab = .95,
        cex.axis = .9, mgp = c(2, .7, 0), tcl = -.3)
    plot(cars)
    boxplot(cars$dist,xlab='dist')
```
",con="figtest.rmd")
rmarkdown::render("figtest.rmd")
browseURL("figtest.html")
````

seems to work fine.

If you need finer control of placement, you'll probably need to embed some HTML directives  -- e.g.

```
<table><tr><td>
## chunk with first figure code
</td><td>
## chunk with second figure code
</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if my issue is a quirk specifically with `filled.contour`, then, because your code does in fact work fine. But when I swap my plotting functions in, they are always on separate lines. If the solution isn't trivial I'll ask a separate question.